# Trouble with a simple Strategy Pattern example

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

The error is:

> FirstPattern.Character.Character' does
>   not contain a constructor that takes 0
>   arguments

Here is the code:

```
public interface WeaponBehavior
{
    void UseWeapon();
}

class SwordBehavior : WeaponBehavior
{
    public void UseWeapon()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A sword as plain as your wife.");
    }
}
```

Then, I have a character class:

```
public abstract class Character
{
    WeaponBehavior weapon;

    public Character(WeaponBehavior wb)
    {
        weapon = wb;
    }

    public void SetWeapon(WeaponBehavior wb)
    {
        weapon = wb;
    }

    public abstract void Fight();
}



public class Queen : Character
{        
    public Queen(WeaponBehavior wb)
    {
        SetWeapon(wb);
    }

    public override void Fight()
    {

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I should be doing with the character class and subclasses. Can you guys nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Queen` is derived from `Character` and `Character` only has a constructor with a `WeaponBehavior` parameter, you need to explicitly call the base constructor in your `Queen` constructor - that means the call to `SetWeapon` you had in there is unnecessary as well:

```
public Queen(WeaponBehavior wb) : base(wb)
{
}
```

Alternatively you could offer a default constructor in `Character` and leave your original code unchanged:

```
public abstract class Character
{
   WeaponBehavior weapon;

   public Character() { }
   ...
```